# Consume a message with an older schema using kafka-avro-console-consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

Is there a way to consume a message with an older schema using kafka-avro-console-consumer? 
I managed to consume the message from a the topic using our schema registry but it seems like it is always using the latest one
enter code here

```
./kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic mytopic --partition 14 --offset 791197 --max-messages 1 --bootstrap-server mybootstrapserver.aws.confluent.cloud:9092 --property schema.registry.url=http://schemaregistry.mydomain --consumer.config consumer.properties
```

Is there a way to specify a particular version of the schema?

Answer (score 0):

In the help function of the `kafka-avro-console-consumer` I could not find an option to specify a particular version of the schema. As far as I understood a good Schema Registry is not meant to provide access to all versions of a schema individually but rather applies the principles of [Schema Evolution](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html#schema-evolution).

In your case, reading *old* data with a *new* schema, the schema has to be [Backward Compatible](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html#backward-compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

Producer specifies the schema while sending the message to the topic. You will receive the exact same message in the consumer. If you are receiving a message in the latest schema format that means the producer is producing that message with the same Avro version format.

Lets see below example:

Schema v1:

```
{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "com.example",
     "name": "Customer",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "first_name", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "last_name", "type": "string" }
     ]
}
```

Schema v2

```
{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "com.example",
     "name": "Customer",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "first_name", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "last_name", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "extra", "type": ["null","string"], "default":null }
     ]
}
```

And you have sent below 3 messages

```
{
  "value":  {"first_name": "raja", "last_name": "bhowmick"}
}
```

with v1

```
{
  "value":  {"first_name": "raja", "last_name": "bhowmick", "extra": { "string":"extra" }}
}
```

with v2

```
{
      "value":  {"first_name": "raja", "last_name": "bhowmick"}
}
```

with v1

Then you will receive message like this

```
[
  {
    "topic": "test",
    "key": null,
    "value": {
      "first_name": "raja",
      "last_name": "bhowmick"
    },
    "partition": 0,
    "offset": 3
  },
  {
    "topic": "test",
    "key": null,
    "value": {
      "first_name": "raja",
      "last_name": "bhowmick",
      "extra": {
        "string": "extra"
      }
    },
    "partition": 0,
    "offset": 4
  },
  {
    "topic": "test",
    "key": null,
    "value": {
      "first_name": "raja",
      "last_name": "bhowmick"
    },
    "partition": 0,
    "offset": 5
  }
]
```